# Posting an array of form values from JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, post

I have an ecommerce site where I can add a product to multiple categories.

I had originally created a form something like this:

```
<form action='parse.php' method='post'>
//other form fields
<input type='checkbox' value='category1' class='product_category' name='product_category[]'>
<input type='checkbox' value='category2' class='product_category' name='product_category[]'>
<input type='checkbox' value='category3' class='product_category' name='product_category[]'>
//other form fields
<input type="submit" value="Go Live" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

And then when they were submitted I could get them in PHP like so:

```
$categories = $_POST['product_category'];
foreach ($categories as $category){//do stuff here}
```

However, now that the website is becoming bigger and products have more data associated with them this is taking too long to parse everything, so was going to try put a return false on my submit and post the stuff to my parse file via AJAX so that I don't have to wait for it to parse everything to reload the page and add more.

So my new form and JS looks like this:

```
<form action='parse' method='post'>
//other form fields
<input type='checkbox' value='category1' class='product_category' name='product_category[]'>
<input type='checkbox' value='category2' class='product_category' name='product_category[]'>
<input type='checkbox' value='category3' class='product_category' name='product_category[]'>
//other form fields
<input type="submit" value="Go Live" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="return false;">
</form>

$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    //get other variables
    var product_category = $('#product_category').val();
    var formData = new FormData();
    //append other values to formdata
    formData.append("product_category", product_category);
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "parse.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

Basically my issue is I was getting an array as my posted variable and now I'm just getting a single value.

How do I get an array of all of the product categories instead of doing `var product_category = $('#product_category').val();` like I'm doing for the rest of my inputs?

Sorry I know there is probably an easy way of doing this but JS is not my best language.

Comment: 1. You are using the ID (#) selector for your product_category checkboxes. Even if previously "product_category" was their ID and not the class as in your current snippet jQuery returns only one element if queried by ID as it is expecting IDs to be unique.
 2. As Laphaze mentioned in his answer check values of checked boxes and put them into array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for every checked checkboxes :

```
$("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
    yourArray.push($(this).val());
});
```

or this if you want every checkbox values :

```
$("input:checkbox").each(function(){
    yourArray.push($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `jQuery.serialize()`: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

And IMHO your markup should be as follow:

```html
<form action='parse.php' method='POST' name="parseForm">
//other form fields
<input type='checkbox' value='category1' class='product_category' name='product_category[]'>
<input type='checkbox' value='category2' class='product_category' name='product_category[]'>
<input type='checkbox' value='category3' class='product_category' name='product_category[]'>
//other form fields
<input type="submit" value="Go Live" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>

<script>
$("form").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let formData = ($(this).serialize());
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "parse.php", true);
    xmlhttp.send(formData);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope this would help you

```
   $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        var formData = [];
        $(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i){
          formData[i] = $(this).val();
        });
        console.log(formData);
       //get other variables

      /* var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
            console.log(this.responseText);
        }
      };
      xmlhttp.open("POST", "parse.php", true);
      xmlhttp.send(formData);  */
     })
```

Also included jsfidde link
https://jsfiddle.net/divyachandana/8jgowxb9/3/